# Calculating stress from elementary tension and bending formulas

Tags: stresses, shear

[image]I need help with this problem.
Suppose we have a cantilever with width $-c \leq y \leq c$ and length $x=l$ fixed at $x=0$. We know that it is loaded by uniform shear along the lower edge with magnitude $S$ and the upper edge and the end $x=l$ are free from load. I know how to find the stresses using the airy stress function, but could you please tell me how to find $\sigma_x$ and $\tau_{xy}$ using the elementary tension and bending formula so that I can compare?

The depth of the beam perpendicular to the x axis is 1.

Comment: Can you provide picture?

Comment: What is the width of the beam perpendicular to the x-axis?

Comment: @JemEripol assume it is 1.

Comment: elementary Euler beam theory does not directly handle the surface shear case. You might replace "s" with an axial force and a distributed moment, although without actually going through all the math its not clear how good an approximation that would yield.